# How to draw a selected text in win32 using only gdi call?

Tags: winapi, gdi

I tried to draw a selected text using two TextOut call and TA_UPDATECP flag but when I move the selected area, the characters are moving a bit.

Does someone know the correct way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN documentation, when you have set the TA_UPDATECP flag using [SetTextAlign()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145091(VS.85).aspx), [TextOut()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145133(VS.85).aspx) ignores its position parameters in favor of the device context's current position. Without seeing your code, I suspect that your drawing algorithm calls TextOut() with a current position that differs slightly based on the selection.

As a debugging strategy, you can call [GetCurrentPositionEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144870(VS.85).aspx) just before you call TextOut() to obtain the current position and make sure it matches your expectation for where the text should be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that antialiasing and ClearType can draw text at fractional pixel positions.  If you draw a string of text, and then try to redraw a portion of the middle, there might not be a way for you to draw text starting at exactly the same position as those characters in the middle.  The trick seems to be to redraw the entire string, but with a clipping region for the selected text.

[Chapter 4 in this tutorial on writing a Win32 text editor](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/neatpad) goes into quite some detail on how to draw selected text.